# if one function result is correct it throws error at another function call in ruby

Tags: ruby, arguments, argument-passing, function

```
def one(a,b)
  if a < 10
      def two(b)
        if b < 10
           print "Both function failed"
        else
           print "ITs passed in second function TWO \n"
        end
       end
   else
       print "ITs passed in first function ONE \n"
   end
 end


one(11,10)
two(10)
```

The output for above program is

```
ITs passed in first function ONE 
test2.rb:18:in `<main>': undefined method `two' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

i know why this error occured

```
test2.rb:18:in `<main>': undefined method `two' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

but what to do if the function one fails

```
 def one(a,b)
  if a < 10
```

if a < 10 if true the i have to proceed with function two

```
 def one(a,b)
  if a < 10
      def two(b)
        if b < 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't define methods inside other methods. While Ruby technically allows it, it's confusing and should just be avoided.

In your example, you run `one(11, 10)`. This will *not* execute the `if a < 10 ... end` branch, meaning that `def two(b) ... end` is never evaluated. As a result, the `two` method is not defined, hence the `NoMethodError`.

You should move the `two` method outside of `one`:

```
def one(a,b)
  if a < 10
    two(b)    
  else
    print "ITs passed in first function ONE \n"
  end
end

def two(b)
  if b < 10
    print "Both function failed"
  else
    print "ITs passed in second function TWO \n"
  end
end

one(11,10) # ITs passed in first function ONE
two(10)    # ITs passed in second function TWO
```